# Query to get time between send and open

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I'm trying to build a query that allows me to study times between an email is sent and the open event from a subscriber.

I'm trying the following but I'm just getting few records for each job, though I know there are lot more.

For the query I limit to one specific `jobid` (263460) but the idea is to replace that condition with date's one.

any idea?

```
SELECT
    o.JobID
    , o.SubscriberKey
    , o.EventDate
    , o.IsUnique
    , j.pickuptime
    ,j.DeliveredTime 
    ,j.emailName
FROM _Open as o with (nolock)
INNER JOIN _Job as j with (nolock) on (j.jobid = o.jobid)
WHERE
o.jobid = '263460'
```

Comment: is this Salesforce query (SOQL) or SQL for other DB?

Comment: I think it's a SQQL. Im writing it as a query activity in Exacttarget, using the platform models (_sent, _open, _job, etc...)

Comment: This query should return all opens for job 263460.  Why do you think this results are incomplete?  Have you compared them to what appears in tracking?